# Render JSON events on full calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, fullcalendar

I'm trying to render events on the fullcalendar from the json response,

```
$.ajax({
        url : $("body").attr("data-link")+'/calendar/events',
        type : 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(e){
            if(e.success){
                var events = [];
                $.each(e.events,function(index,value){
                    events.push({
                        title : value.title,
                        start : moment(value.start_date).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                        end : moment(value.end_date).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                    });
                });
                calendar.fullCalendar( 'renderEvent', events , true);
                console.log(events);
            }
        }
    });
```

here's my fullcalendar set up

```
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        customButtons: {
            myCustomButton: {
                text: 'Add Event',
                click: function() {

                }
            }
        },
         header: {
            left: 'prev,next today myCustomButton',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable : false,
        eventLimit: true,
        eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view, element) {
        },
        eventRender: function(event, element) {
            element.attr("data-id",event.id);
        },

    });
```

In the console log.

[image]

and then it gives me this error,

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasTime' of undefined

any ideas, help please?

Comment: does the log to console look correct?

Comment: yes., in the console log, its correct

Comment: Does `console.log(events);` prints all events correctly?

Comment: Please see my updated post.

Comment: Are you sure there is `renderEvents` method?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko: I just copied it somewhere here in stackoverflow but as I searched just now, there's no actualy 'renderEvents' method, so I changed it to 'renderEvent' instead, please see my updated post, upon using 'renderEvent', it throws me this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasTime' of undefined" any ideas?

Comment: `renderEvent` sounds like it accepts a single event :) not entire array.

Comment: please see my updated post.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko: so any ideas, help on how to make it accept the entire array please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either call `renderEvent` for each event in `events` or add entire array as datasource

```
$.ajax({
        url : $("body").attr("data-link")+'/calendar/events',
        type : 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(e){
            if(e.success){
                var events = [];
                $.each(e.events,function(index,value){
                    events.push({
                        title : value.title,
                        start : moment(value.start_date).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                        end : moment(value.end_date).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                    });
                });
                calendar.fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', events);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: BTW you can use functions as eventsource. [Docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/).